# How to perform async operation from Angular interceptor?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, interceptor

I'm trying to perform an async operation before issuing a network request.

For some reason the network request doesn't even start.
I basically want the request to hold until the next function in `accessToken$` observable is fired.

As far as I understand I piped the `accessToken$` with the observable that is returned from `next.handle(req)` resulting a middlewear `then(..).then(..)` behavior.

code:

```
public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const accessToken$: Observable<string> = from("accessToken");

    return accessToken$.pipe(mergeMap((accessToken: string) => {
        req = req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                'Authorization' : `${accessToken}`,
            }
        })
        return next.handle(req);
    }));
}
```

I am trying to figure out why this middlewear behavior isn't working. Or why it is working but the interceptor still hold the request from going out for some reason.

Worth mentioning that if I just return `next.handle(req)` the request does go through. So my heart tells me that there's something wrong with the observable interaction I defined.

I followed this tutorial:
[Async HTTP Interceptors with Angular 4.3](https://medium.com/@danielcrisp/async-http-interceptors-with-angular-4-3-9e6e795da562)

Comment: if you put a console.log does the part before the return run? Does it hit your interceptor at all?

Comment: Also lets see what this.authTokensManager.getAccessTokenForEndpoint(req.url) does

Comment: Yes Im debugging the code and it even hits the next.handle(req)

Comment: this.authTokensManager.getAccessTokenForEndpoint(req.url) just creates a rxjs Subject and after getting the token it calls its next function

Comment: Please post the code for authTokensManager. A subject won't emit it's current value when you subscribe. You would need replay or behavior subject which could be an issue depending on how the code looks. Your interceptor code looks like standard auth interceptor code, so the issue cannot be there. It's doing what its supposed to, so we need to take a look at the observable its piping.

Comment: I simplified my code with `from("accessToken")` instead of `this.authTokensManager.getAccessTokenForEndpoint(req.url)` and still doesn't sned the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a catch error, does it log anything in the output?

```
  public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const accessToken$: Observable<string> = of("accessToken");

    return accessToken$.pipe(mergeMap((accessToken: string) => {
      const tokenRequest = req.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          'Authorization': `${accessToken}`,
        }
      });
      return next.handle(tokenRequest);
    }),
      catchError((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        return throwError(error);
      }));
  }
```

Comment: This helped to see the error that somehow was hidden before - not output to console or throw anywhere. The error was a custom header I entered that wasn't good. Thanks @shadowfox476!